# BertTokenizer Loading Problem

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, bert

I loaded this BertTokenizer previously, but now it is showing, I have to make sure I don't have a local directory. In my kaggle kernel, I don't have this local directory.
How to solve it?

```
class Config:
    DEVICE = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
    LR = 2e-5
    TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE = 16
    TEST_BATCH_SIZE = 8
    EPOCHS = 10
    N_FOLD = 5
    TOKENIZER = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-large-uncased', do_lower_case=True)
    CLASSES = 3
    MAX_LEN = 200
    TRAIN_CSV = ".csv"
    TEST_CSV = "test.csv"
    API = "#"
    PROJECT_NAME = "bert-base2"
    MODEL_NAME = "bert-large-uncased"
```

```
OSError: Can't load tokenizer for 'bert-large-uncased'. If you were trying to load it from 'https://huggingface.co/models', make sure you don't have a local directory with the same name. Otherwise, make sure 'bert-large-uncased' is the correct path to a directory containing all relevant files for a BertTokenizer tokenizer.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be due to an internet connection issue, that's why it is always safer to download your model in a local folder first and then load it directly using the absolute path.

In addition to that bert large is about 2Gb.

To download it, you can use this code:

```
git lfs install
git clone https://huggingface.co/bert-large-uncased
```

See also: https://huggingface.co/bert-large-uncased